# MySQL restore bd from directory copy

Tags: mysql-5.5, recovery

MySQL restore bd from directory copy.
Hello, I recently lost the external storage where my MySQL data directory was located, but I have copied the entire data directory in another location, the problem is that I copied it without stopping mysql before, I would like to know how to get mysql from the directory data where information is saved before the crash

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, you are probably SOL.

Case 1:  Copying the disk while MySQL is actively writing data.  Very likely to be in an inconsistent state -- some things written to disk and copied; some not.

Case 2:  MySQL up during the copy, but not actively writing (`UPDATE`, `INSERT`, etc).  This *might* work since it is identical to a power failure.